# How do I find most common items in a list and occurrences in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python and I'm looking to find a relatively simple way to get the top 10 most common items in a list with their occurrences. I saw some solutions however I'm not sure which solution is the best if I'm counting occurrences.

Is there a structure that is best suited for this type of use?

Comment: `collections.Counter(lst).most_common(10)`

Answer (score 1):

with pandas it could be:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]).value_counts()
```

This will give:

```
3    5
1    3
2    2
dtype: int64
```